# Rooting GT-i9100G under linux

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, linux

What is the safest method to root a Samsung Galaxy S 2 i9100 **G** under a GNU/Linux system? (ArchLinux).

I am a programmer (without android programming experience, only desktop and web), it does not need to be "one click away", but the method has to be safe **and you've tried it** and it works.

I have adb installed and it works, if rooting the phone involves using it too.

```
Android version: 2.3.6
Baseband version: i9100gxxkl4
Build number: gingerbread.xxlb1
```

Comment: Rooting can be **never** completely safe.

Comment: Ok, not completely safe, but at least you've tried it, for this model number, this version, this build number. So I need a solution under these conditions from someone who has done it with success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1246131) should get you started. Please, carefully check your versions to make sure the files you use are intended for your phone.