# Rooting Galaxy I9100 S11 Jellybean without changing ROM

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rooting

Am looking for a simple safe way to uninstall some Vodaphone branded apps without changing the ROM (if possible) I expect rooting will be necessary and possibly a temporary ROM will be required to do this.  I can live with the majority of the installed apps, it is just the brandings I dislike.  My main concern is that there appear to be 2 separate web Vodaphone browsers one is clearly badged, the other appears to be clean (but isn't) If I uninstall these I might be locked out of web access.  I have recently updated to Jellybean 4.1.2 and wonder if I will lose this if I root.

The following is phone info:  Baseband I9100BULS1
                              Kernel:  3.0.31-889555
                                       dpi @ DELL 228#3
                                       SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan31 14:48:54
                                       KST 2013
                              Build No:JZO54K.I9100XWLSD

Am new to this, keen to understand and anxious to get it right.  Any advice would be much appreciated.  Many thanks

Comment: Have you checked with our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/16575), as the tag-wiki for "rooting" suggests? Maybe the methods mentioned for either [GT-I9100P](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28662/16575) or [GT-I9100G](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22768/16575) do work for you?

Comment: I have read up on forums and checked on the web for guidance. I understand the principle but do not want to change the current ROM. I believe I will need to run a different ROM to access the software and remove the annoying bloatware.  Once I have done that I want to return the phone to how it was before rooting, this is where I am unsure if an unroot will replace the bloat. Having upgraded twice from gingerbread to ice cream sandwich and now to jellybean I wonder if I will have to re do all of these or just the jellybean.  Lots of queries, just lack enough information.

Comment: You won't need another ROM (in fact, usually you will need to root your device to install a new ROM -- not the other way around). Have you checked the links I posted in my previous comment? A short explanation you also find in the tag wiki for "rooting" (simply hover your mouse over the tag, and select "info" in the popup).