# Root Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.XX?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rooting, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I need to Root Samsung Galaxy S 2, GT-I9100, with XXKI4 
I need to Root it with Room Android 2.3.5 or any version within 2.3.X
while searching I just found Android versions above this version all with 4.XX??

Any suggestion for Android version 2.3.X ??

Comment: Did you see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1125414 ? The guy at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1732783 says it worked for him on 2.3. But why don't you just upgrade to 4.X then root?

Comment: Have you seen [Rooting Stock Firmware - GSII with NFC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28662/16575) (Gingerbread + ICS), and [Rooting GT-i9100G under linux](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22768/16575) (Gingerbread)?

Comment: @dotVezz
I need this version 2.3.XX necessary, but the link talk about Ice cream sandwich that is mean version 4.0 ??(I9100 Insecure and Original ICS Kernels)
I didn't see android 2.3.X , can you help me please to see these ?

Comment: @Izzy
this answer talk about ICS, it also talk about different kernel they use I9100PBVLP7 but my Kernel is I9100XXKI4 ?
this will not work!! right ?

Comment: @Hanaa The first link is a root method for 2.3. The second link is just discussion.

Comment: what difference between GT-I9100_JPKJ2_insecure and

 GT-I9100_XXKI4_original

are same doable to root on android 2.3.X ?