# Is it safe to root samsung galaxy s2?

Tags: stock-android

Okay I have never rooted a phone and from what I have heard, rooting can cause bricking. Can you guys tell me lile is it safe to do so? And give me link of some easy and safe tutorials? Thanks :)

Comment: Rooting doesn't cause bricking. Rooting *improperly*  may cause bricking

Comment: As for how to root your S2, we'd need to know *which* S2 it is: [Galaxy S2 GT-i9100](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88717/1465) / [GT-I9100 P](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28662/16575) / [GT-I9100 G](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22768/16575)?

Comment: @Izzy Or AT&T's i777, i727, T-Mo's T989, Sprint's D710... Too many fundamentally different S2s.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's never safe to go behind what the manufacturer had set out for you. Cons of rooting include but aren't limited to

1. High risk of bricking phone (corrupting the bootloader rendering the phone particularly useless)
2. Voiding warranty

For beginners I'd recommend kingo root app. You literally just [download](http://king.myapp.com/myapp/kdown/img/NewKingrootV4.9.6_C151_B309_en_release_2016_08_18_105203.apk) the app and they'll do the rest for you. Kingo also has a lesser chance of bricking your phone/failing to root.

Other ways of rooting include loading a custom rom through the bootloader for your specific phone model but as you said you're a beginner and I wouldn't advise you to go this way until you feel more comfortable having understood the ways of rooting a phone.

.